# How to handle different hash symbols for hashtag

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have a filter that finds hashtag in text and replaces it with link.

I am using this `/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim` regular expression to find hashtag, but it only detects the "#" symbol (Unicode Decimal Code &#35) and I received the "＃" symbol (Unicode Decimal Code &#65283) from android device. I can't find any similar questions. Is is just my problem?

> 1. Can I detect &#65283 symbol?
> 2. What is better to do in this case? Try to find all hash symbols and replace them with &#35 symbol or have multiple regular expressions
>      or anything else?
> 3. Is there is more hash symbols?

Comment: Try this: `/(^|\s)[#|\x{FF03}](\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim`

Comment: It did not help. This expression replaces "#" and "f".

Comment: `/(^|\s)[#|\uff03](\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim` worked. Thanks for idea @NicolasMaltais